# Add link to newsletters on Stack Exchange main site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, newsletter

I heard about the [newsletter subscription page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) on the Stack Exchange main site (from the podcast), and noticed that there was no link anywhere on the Stack Exchange site for it.  Maybe something in the sidebar would be nice.

Comment: it's still a little experimental, but we have a ton of house ads for the newsletter. Also go to your user page and click edit, and look at the sidebar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) has a [newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) link in the main nav now.